# Validation of radiobuttonlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to validate radiobuttonlist if user is not checked any item. If not checked whole list should be highlighted. Following is my code:

```
var userImpect = document.getElementById("<%=userImpect.ClientID%>");
for (var i = 0; i < userImpect.length; i++) { 
    if (userImpect[i].checked) {
        userImpect.style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
        validate = false;
    }                        
}                    
return validate;
```

Please tell me how to do it.
***Here is my asp code***

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="userImpect" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Just me" Value="Just me"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Users" Value="Multiple Users"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Everyone" Value="Everyone"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

***Button code***

```
<asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateForm();" />
```

***html generated***
[image]

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is generated for your list?

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way :

document.getElementById("userImpect").style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";

Comment: issue in If condition :  if (userImpect[i].checked)

Comment: Replace this code :

 if (userImpect[i].checked) {

with this :

 if (userImpect[i].checked ==  true) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148463/discussion-between-rami-far-and-dilip).

Answer (score 0):

Give all your checkboxes a class name say 'involved'. With JQuery you can do this:
`$('.involved :checked').length == 0`

Comment: How to name the class?

Comment: class="involved" on your ListItem

Comment: Ok done it. now where to put above given piece of code. can you please edit your answer using my given code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomValidator` to check if a value has been selected and color the html table accordingly.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="userImpect" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Just me" Value="Just me"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Users" Value="Multiple Users"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Everyone" Value="Everyone"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ClientValidationFunction="checkRadioList"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkRadioList(oSrc, args) {
        var a = document.getElementById('<%=userImpect.ClientID %>').style;
        if ($("input[name='<%= userImpect.UniqueID %>']:checked").val() == null) {
            args.IsValid = false;
            a.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
            a.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to use validator

Comment: Remove the validator part. The code to change the colors if no radio is selected stays the same.